# Is it possible read a pdf file in JAVA and save particular words alone?

Tags: java, pdf-reader

I am developing an application in java, In this application i have to read pdf file and save contents. For ex:

**A pdf file contains:**

Xxxxxxxxxxxx: yyyyyyyyyy

yyyyyyyyyyyy: zzzzzz, zzzzzz ,zzzzzz ,yyyyyy

I have to save the value of Xxxxxxx and yyyyyyyyyy in database are some where.

Is it possible to do?

Any Tutorials really its so helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[Itext](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275) is best library available in Java for PDF handling..

Comment: niiraj874u@: I have used Itext jar file already. It reads by page by page successfully. I have to read it by delimiter

Comment: I have extracted the text. How to take particular parameter value in that PDF?

Comment: Thomas Uhrig @ :How to get particular line values